# what does "~/." mean in terms of OS X folders/directories?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm installing a program on my MacBook that has to be unzipped to the ~/.spring directory; now, I know what Spring is, it's the name of the thing I'm installing. I'd be very happy to create a .spring folder if I knew what ~/. meant.

Comment: Note: `~/.` by itself means something different than when it is a prefix of something longer. On its own, it is a longer way of writing `~`, both of which indicate the home directory. As a prefix (e.g `~/.spring`) it indicates a “hidden” entry in the home directory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The tilde symbol (~) in OS X command-line terminology refers to your home directory, e.g /Users/Joe.

As JonathanMueller pointed out, anything with a dot (.) in front, is considered hidden. Thus, what your program needs you to do is to:

1. Fire up ***Terminal***
2. ***cd ~*** (goes to your home directory)
3. ***mkdir .spring*** (creates a hidden spring directory)

You will not be able to see this folder in Finder, as it is hidden, but going to Terminal and using ***ls -a*** while in Terminal will show up the hidden folders.

Comment: Why sometimes this is going to /root?

Answer (score 4):

~ is a reference to the home directory. A dot directory is a "hidden" directory in UNIX.

Comment: anything with a dot append in front is hidden in Unix, but in this case, a singular dot refers to the current directory, which is Home.

Comment: @caliban You sure about that?  If the dot in `~/.spring` refers to the current directory, OS X strayed a lot farther from its Unix origins than I had imagined.

Comment: @caliban, a single dot refers to the current directory and two dots refer to the parent directory, but this question was about .spring, which would be a hidden directory. Thanks for pointing out the possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To view 'hidden' files, use

```
ls -a
```

or add -a to your usual 'ls' arguments.  The -a flag is implied if you have superuser privs.

Comment: Or `-A` to not display the `.` and `..` entries.